# showNotification() in static android

Tags: android, static, notifications

I want my app to make a notification after the user toggles a switch in settings. The settings page is static so I can't use showNotification() here. Is there any way to build a notification like that??

```
public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);

                final SwitchPreference notiswitch = (SwitchPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_notification_key));
                notiswitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                        if(!((Boolean) newValue)) {     //default false
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OFF",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ON",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //TODO make notification
                            showNotification();//error here

                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
}

public void showNotification() {
```

Comment: You didn't added the code of showNotification. Also, please attach your logcat.

Comment: showNotification is just a simple notification. The problem is that the first showNotification is underlined red and says it is non-static and couldn't be referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you made `MainPreferenceFragment` as static inner class inside an activity class which contains the `showNotification()` method and serves as host for the fragment.

My suggestion is to use a classic approach of `activity-fragment` communication - through the casting fragment's hosting activity to the required interface and call appropriate method from it.

For example:

Create a new interface in separate file:

```
public interface NotificationView{
    void showNotification();
}
```

Then make the activity that responsible for showing fragment implementing the interface, and override the `showNotification` method.

After that add to the `MainPreferenceFragment` class a private field `NotificationView callback;` and initialize it in this way:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) { 
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceOf NotificationView){
        callback = (NotificationView) activity;
    }
}
```

And now you are able to call `callback.showNotification();` from where you need inside your fragment. But don't forget to check callback on `null` before using in case you use the fragment with other activity.

Hope it will help!

Comment: Sir, I think I am now about to success, but callback.showNotification(); has an error there says callback might not have been initialized.

Comment: Make sure that you are adding the fragment to the activity that implements NotificationView interface

Comment: I did, it says callback is not initialized.

Comment: Is `NotificationView callback = something;`??